# Loop UISlider from left to right and vice versa in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, slider

I want to move a `UISlider` from left to right and as soon as it hits `maximumValue` it shall move to the left until it hits `minimumValue` and then move again to `maximumValue`.

I'm using this code including a timer for slow movement.

But the problem is as soon as it hits `maximumValue` it moves one increment behind the first if cause gets triggered and it moves forwards again leading the slider to jump one step back and forth in a loop as soon as `maximumValue` was hit.

I've already tried using the backwards boolean variable to tell the if cause it shall only move backwards but initial false value gets picked up very 'round'.

I hope you got the concept.

```
@IBAction func setSliderValue(_ sender: UIButton){
        mytimer =  Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(timerAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }


    func timerAction(){
        let Range =  slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue;
        let Increment = Range/100;
        var newval = slider.value + Increment;
        var backwards : Bool = false

        if(slider.value != slider.maximumValue && backwards == false){
            slider.setValue(newval, animated: true)
            print("The value of the slider is now \(slider.value)")
            sliderValue = Int(slider.value)
            print("1. \(backwards)")
        }
        else if (slider.value == slider.maximumValue || slider.value != slider.maximumValue){
            newval = slider.value - 1
            print("newval : \(newval)")
            print("slider.value : \(slider.value)")
            slider.setValue(newval, animated: true)
            backwards = true
            print("2. \(backwards)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting timer on button click in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41375408/starting-timer-on-button-click-in-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move UISlider automatically in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361451/move-uislider-automatically-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is about the same as the above. It is more the style notation that i would recommend since it adds to the readability of your project:
(camelCase for normal variables / Capitalize Classes, enums to distinguish possible states instead of if/else)

```
var sliderState = SliderState.Incrementing
enum SliderState {
    case Incrementing
    case Decrementing

}

func timerAction() {
    let range =  slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue
    let increment = range/100

    switch slider.value {
    case slider.maximumValue:
        sliderState = .Decrementing
    case slider.minimumValue:
        sliderState = .Incrementing
    default:
        break
    }

    switch sliderState {
    case .Incrementing:
        slider.setValue(slider.value + increment, animated: true)
    case .Decrementing:
        slider.setValue(slider.value - increment, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this looks pretty nice, I'll give you that. But I'm pretty sure you need to use the slider.setValue func as slider.value should be read only.

Comment: You are right in a way i noticed. I saw value { get set } and the documentation stated: "Use this property to get and set the slider’s current value". So it isn't read-only. But: "To render an animated transition from the current value to the new value, use the setValue(_:animated:) method instead." So ill use that one, thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're going to use `UISlider.setValue(_:animated:)`, animations usuaully take 0.25 to 0.30 seconds to run. Thus it doesn't make much sense to run the slider update timer every .1 seconds. The OP should probably increase the timer interval to 0.25 or 0.30 to get smoother animation. (And then increase the increment value proportionally so the whole animation still takes the same amount of time.)

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that your timerAction func is being called every 0.1 seconds, and you are trying to use the backwards bool as some sort of indicator of which way the slider is moving, but every time you are calling the func, you are setting the bool to false in the fourth line. Thus, in order to accomplish what you are trying to do you will need to declare the bool as a class variable.

Second of all, some of your code just doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me. I will include a version that I think is better below:

```
var backwards : Bool = false

func timerAction(){
    let Range =  slider.maximumValue - slider.minimumValue;
    let Increment = Range/100;
    var newval = slider.value + Increment;

    if(slider.value != slider.maximumValue && backwards == false){ //then slider is moving forwards
        slider.setValue(newval, animated: true)
    }
    else if (slider.value == slider.maximumValue){ //slider needs to turn around
        backwards = true
        slider.setValue(slider.value - Increment, animated: true)
    }
    else if (slider.value == slider.minimumValue){ //slider needs to turn around
        backwards = false
        slider.setValue(slider.value + Increment, animated: true)
    }
    else if (backwards == true){ //slider is moving backwards
        slider.setValue(slider.value + Increment, animated: true)
    }

    sliderValue = Int(slider.value)
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately it got the same problem as mine, as soon as the slider hits maximumValue it jumps back and forth.